# Laravel - Parameters are not forward by the route

Tags: php, laravel

**Route**

```
Route::get('restaurants/@{latitude},{longitude},{radius}', 'RestaurantsController@nearbyRestaurants');
```

I tried doing my own request at first, then did directly a validator in the controller

**Controller's methode**

```
 public function nearbyRestaurants(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'latitude' => 'digits_between:-90,90',
            'longitude' => 'digits_between:-180,180',
            'radius' => 'numeric'
        ]);

        dd($validator);
}
```

**Results of dd(valisator)**

```
#initialRules: array:3 [▼
    "latitude" => "digits_between:-90,90"
    "longitude" => "digits_between:-180,180"
    "radius" => "numeric"
  ]
  #rules: array:3 [▼
    "latitude" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "digits_between:-90,90"
    ]
    "longitude" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "digits_between:-180,180"
    ]
    "radius" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "numeric"
    ]
  ]
```

**Solution**

Instead of :

```
public function nearbyRestaurants(Request $request)
{

}
```

*Use*

```
public function nearbyRestaurants($latitude, $longitude, $radius)
{

}
```

Using dd($validator); i can now see the data:

```
#data: array:3 [▼
    0 => "59.93141200"
    1 => "30.31992300"
    2 => "15"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting from the URL are arguments for the controller, not arguments from the `$_GET` and `$_POST` global, which is what the validator needs. What you want is this:

```
public function nearbyRestaurants(Request $request, $latitude, $longitude, $radius)
```

Then, manually create a validator and pass those in as items.

Comment: So instead of : 

`\Validator::make($request->all(),`

 
`\Validator::make([$latitude, $longitude, $radius]`

is it right ? i can get rid of Request $request then ?

Comment: You could. You'd probably need a 'keyname'=>$value association in that array, though.